# How to solve EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'build/..' - Docker + Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am using this docker [file](https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) to setup a server at Digital Ocean. I am getting the following errors

```
    EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'build/emails'
    api_1_5a1c41662228 | EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'build/routes'
    api_1_5a1c41662228 | EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'build/schema'
    api_1_5a1c41662228 | EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'build/utils'
    api_1_5a1c41662228 | EACCES: permission denied, open 'build/Context.js'

    and so on for a long time.
```

#### I have tried the following things

1. Chown almost everything there is to be.
2. Tried it on the different versions of OS
3. Read various blogs about Docker and giving it root access and tried those solutions.

I am using the most recent version of docker.

P.S. It runs perfectly on Mac. Sadly there are no Mac servers.

#### More info

`ls -ltr` on the folder

```
[root@relay-server-centos fusionauth-relay]# ls -ltr /usr/src/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 1001  6 Apr 11  2018 kernels
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 1001  6 Apr 11  2018 debug
drwxr-xr-x. 3 1001 1001 19 Apr  5 11:24 app
```

Comment: what do you mean by `Chown almost everything there is to be. ` ? Could you paste the permission of folders by doing `ls -ltr` on that directory?

Comment: Does `build` exist? Try `mkdir -p`

Comment: @Sohan Added the output of ls -ltr.                                                     
       `[root@relay-server-centos fusionauth-relay]# ls -ltr /usr/src/
        total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 1001  6 Apr 11  2018 kernels
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 1001  6 Apr 11  2018 debug
drwxr-xr-x. 3 1001 1001 19 Apr  5 11:24 app`

Comment: @tripleee Created `build` on my own because the docker was not creating it. :|

Comment: What *exactly* ase you doing when you get this error? You're not linking to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter/blob/master/Dockerfile) but it seems to create this directory on line 20 (provided you pass in `--build-arg NODE_ENV="test"` or generally anything except `"production"`)

Comment: I am simply running `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it right now using the root user, which is a really horrible way to do it. But I am out of ideas right now and any help would be welcomed.